# Number date to Alphabetic in awk

Tags: date, awk, 2-digit-year

I have a file:
ifile.txt

```
83080603   55  72
87090607   83  87
88010612   82  44
89080603   55  72
00110607   83  87
01030612   82  44
05120618   84  44
```

The 1st column shows the date and time with the format YYMMDDHH.

I would like to print the first column as hrHDDMMMYYYY
ofile.txt

```
03H06Aug1983   55  72
07H06Sep1987   83  87
12H06Jan1988   82  44

and so on
```

I can't able to convert the digit month-year to text month. My script is

```
awk '{printf "%s%5s%5s\n",
substr($0,7,2)"H"substr($0,5,2)substr($0,3,2)substr($0,1,2), $2, $3}' ifile.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Adding solution as per OP's comment for adding year as per condition here.

```
awk -v curr_year=$(date +%y) '
BEGIN{
  num=split("Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec",arr,",")
  for(j=1;j<=num;j++){
    key=sprintf("%02d",j)
    months[key]=arr[j]
  }
}
{
  year=substr($1,1,2)>=00 && substr($1,1,2)<=curr_year?"20":"19"
  $1=substr($1,length($1)-1)"H"substr($1,length($1)-3,2) months[substr($1,3,2)] year substr($1,1,2)
  print
  year=""
}
' Input_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following, written on mobile and successfully tested it on site https://ideone.com/4zYMu7  this also assume that since your Input_file first 2 letters denote year and you want to print only 19 in case there is another logic to get exact year then please do mention it

```
awk '
BEGIN{ 
  num=split("Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec",arr,",")
  for(j=1;j<=num;j++){
    key=sprintf("%02d",j)
    months[key]=arr[j]
  }
}
{
  $1=substr($1,length($1)-1)"H"substr($1,length($1)-3,2) months[substr($1,3,2)] "19" substr($1,1,2)
  print
}
' Input_file
```

Comment: Yes, my data has year after 2000, which is not being considered here. For example `00110607` should print `07H06Nov2000` .

Comment: @Kay, could you please do lemme know how we could recognize if it should print 19 or 20?

Comment: Would it be possible to apply a condition, if `YY >= 00 then YYYY=20YY, else 19YY`. In other words, `if substr($1,1,2) >= 00 then print "20"substr($1,1,2), else print "19"substr($1,1,2)`

Comment: @Kay, ok so you mean from `00` to till current year it should be 20 added and rest of the years it should be `19` right? Kindly confirm on same once.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk:

```sh
awk -v OFS="  " '
    function totime(t,     c, y, m, d, h) {
        y = substr(t, 1 ,2)
        m = substr(t, 3, 2)
        d = substr(t, 5, 2)
        h = substr(t, 7, 2)
        c = y >= 69 ? 19 : 20   # GNU date treats years 69-99 as 19xx else 20xx
        return mktime(c y " " m " " d " " h " 0 0")
    }
    function transformTime(t) {
        return strftime("%HH%d%b%Y", totime(t))
    }
    {
        $1 = transformTime($1)
        print
    }
' ifile.txt
```

```
03H06Aug1983  55  72
07H06Sep1987  83  87
12H06Jan1988  82  44
03H06Aug1989  55  72
07H06Nov2000  83  87
12H06Mar2001  82  44
18H06Dec2005  84  44
```

---

Or, Perl

```sh
perl -MTime::Piece -lane '
    $F[0] = Time::Piece->strptime($F[0], "%y%m%d%H")->strftime("%HH%d%b%Y");
    print join("  ", @F);
' ifile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
        t[i] = substr($1, 2*i+1, 2);
    }
    d = t[0]"-"t[1]"-"t[2]" "t[3]":00";
    cmd = "date --date='"d"' +%HH%d%b%Y";
    cmd | getline $1;
    close(cmd);
    print
}
```

Save the above as `script.awk` and run as `awk -f script.awk ifile.txt`. It uses the `date` command for date format conversion.

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk for `gensub()`. Since you're using GNU awk, though, you don't need to call an external `date` as GNU awk has it's own time functions, and  that's not a safe way to call `getline`, see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline.

Comment: Thank you @Ed. I did not know that. I removed `gensub()`. I also read your article on `getline`, but I could not find a better way to read on line from a pipe.

Comment: The correct syntax would be `if ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ) $1=line`.

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    split("Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec",mths)
}
{
    for (i=1; i<length($1); i+=2) {
        t[(i-1)/2+1] = substr($1,i,2)
    }
    $1 = t[4] "H" t[3] mths[t[2]+0] "19" t[1]
    print
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
03H06Aug1983 55 72
07H06Sep1987 83 87
12H06Jan1988 82 44
03H06Aug1989 55 72
07H06Nov1900 83 87
12H06Mar1901 82 44
18H06Dec1905 84 44
```